# Xcode 8 beta 6 - conflicting values for architecture

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to install my app on a device using Xcode beta 6, and it fails on the linking stage with the following error:

```
ld: linking module flags 'Objective-C Class Properties': IDs have conflicting values for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Xcode 8 beta 3 was building the app successfully, what may be the problem here?

Comment: This looks like an LTO issue: you should file a bug with Apple. Try to add "-Wl,-debug_snapshot" to the clang invocation so that the linker produces a reproduction that you can attach to the bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try turning off Link Time Optimization (LLVM_LTO) for your build. I hope they fix that for the final release.

Comment: It was already turned off, tried all other options for this setting to no avail.

Comment: LTO was turned on for one of the included projects, which was building a static library which was included in my app.. Turned off and the build passed, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I've been facing similar issue in my non-Xcode project.

I started seeing these messages when I upgraded Xcode to version 12.

My setup consists of several 3rd party libraries and the main project which depends on them and on a few macOS system Frameworks. The project is CMake-based.

I tried to rebuild everything with the new Xcode version with no luck. But I can confirm that this is LTO related. (Yes, I'm building the 3rd party libraries with thin LTO as well.)

The sudden change happened when I set proper `-isysroot` to the latest macOS release – 11. Then the linker started to complain about minimum OSX release, specifically that is too old. When I set it to 10.15 (which is my current macOS) the issue disappeared completely.

The solution hence is:

- set `-mmacosx-version-min=10.15`
- set `-isysroot` to `MacOSX11.1.sdk`, e.g.: `-isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk` (`MacOSX.sdk` is a symlink to the lates one)

Note: I'm using `-isysroot` from Command Line Tools but some `autoconf` stuff resolves to the `Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/...` latest SDK as well with no issues. The two SDKs – one from Xcode itself and the other one from Command Line Tools – are compatible.

Note/2: I'm posting the solution here as this question is the most relevant one.

Answer (score 0):

This is because Xcode 8 cannot LTO when there is a mix of files that contains class properties in categories and files that contains categories but that have been generated by Xcode 7 (or prior).
The only workaround for now seems to be to rebuild all the files with Xcode 8.